# Is there a way to convert inconsistent string time to python time object?

Tags: python, datetime

I have timestamp like this.

```
12:30PM
11AM
```

I realise I can use `strptime` to convert that. However, if some of the string doesn't have minute is there a way to auto detect that in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) can help with that:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("12:30PM")
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 12, 30)
>>> parse("11AM")
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 11, 0)
```